# strange behavior when running process using process class vs cmd c#

Tags: c#, process, console-application

I want to run Iperf via c# 
when running via cmd everything works fine and fast 
but I run it via c# using this code :

```
public void RunProcess(string FileName, string Arguments, bool EventWhenExit )
{
    process = new Process();

    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceivedEvent);
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    process.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = false;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.FileName = FileName; // Gets or sets the application or document to start.
    process.StartInfo.Arguments =Arguments;//Gets or sets the set of command-line arguments to use when starting the application      
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (EventWhenExit)
    {
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

        process.Exited += new EventHandler(myprocess_Exited);/*New line */

    }

    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    PID = process.Id;


}

private void myprocess_Exited(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    process.Refresh();
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    onProcessEnd(this, "ENDOF " + Proc.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Process exsiting ");
}


private void OnDataReceivedEvent(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{

    string OutputFromProcess = e.Data;
    //fire event to event handler class for further use
    onDataOutputFromProcess(this, OutputFromProcess, Proc.ToString());
}
```

I get wrong strange behavior : 
when running 1 stream (those of you who use Iperf will know...) every works fine in console and my application (`winform`)
but I run 3 streams and above , my application wont go over and than just hangs when it should exit

what can be the problem ?
what can be a good work around this problem ?

Comment: For code that's not working, please create a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you.

Comment: I'll work on it :)
in the mean while can you tell me if something is wrong with the way I set the process in my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should avoid using Thread.Sleep(x) at any cost.

And i assume you are not using a backgroundWorker or a new Thread to execute the IPerf processes?

I think the backgroundworker would work well for you. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx)

In addition:

A cmd program is in most cases very linear.

A WinForm program not. You have to sepereate GUI and Work-Thread.
the GUI is only for Input and Display. Everthing else you should do in another Thread, because otherwise you will block the GUI.

Comment: maybe it is not clear here and I'm sorry for that , but actually I do exactly what you mentioned . my GUI is separate and the Thread.Sleep is there only to make a small delay (I'll take it down)

Comment: do you use a delegate Event to report the ouput?

Comment: do you use the same event for every backroundworker?

Comment: It's just guessing, but could it be if two backgroundworker call the event at the same time a global variable gets screwed?

Comment: You mean the event OnDataOutputFromProcess ?